# Selecting the first row of SlickGrid

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, slickgrid

I tried the below and i still don't see the row being highlighted. I am using RowSelectionModel. when i click on a row on slick grid it highlights fine. i just need to mimic the click on row behaviour on first row.

```
$("#txtMarket").on("keyup", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        self.SlickGrid.focus();
        self.SlickGrid.resetActiveCell();
        self.SlickGrid.setSelectedRows([0]);
        self.SlickGrid.onClick.notify({ row: 0 });
    }
});
```

No errors are displayed and no row becomes highlighted/selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using jquery solved it.

```
$(".slick-cell:first").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without more of your code. How is self.SlickGrid defined? If it’s an Observable you need to access it like a function using **()**:

```
self.SlickGrid().focus();
self.SlickGrid().resetActiveCell();
self.SlickGrid().setSelectedRows([0]);
self.SlickGrid().onClick.notify({ row: 0 });
```

This is because ko.observable objects are actually functions. In this case you want the value so you have to call the function with no parameters.

More info about ko.observable here: https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Comment: Hi Stig. Thanks for your response. self.SlickGrid is not an observable